# Conditional Split same condition to two different tables

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I want the same output from a Conditional Split to go to two different tables.

I'm importing data from a flat file.  The first character on each line has a "T" or "P".  I'm only importing the "T" lines.  I used a Conditional Split for this and it works great.

Now I'd like to send that same output to another table and can't figure this out.  I've got an Output Name TLINE set as RecordType == "T".  This works for the first table.  I tried creating another Output Name TLINE2 set as RecordType == "T" and != "P".  Everything runs fine but the data never gets to my second table.

Thanks much for any suggestions!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to split the dataflow and send the exact same rows down two different paths, use a `Multicast` transformation instead of a `Conditional Split`.

If you need the `Conditional Split` to get only the "T" rows, you can put the `Multicast` AFTER the `Conditional Split` to send all the "T" rows to two different tables.

Comment: Awesome!  I didn't know about Multicast.  Thanks very much!